# Check 50 Error in Cash App for CS50 Harvard

Tags: c, cs50

Very new to coding, so any help is appreciated, been stuck on these check errors for a while.

```c
//source codde
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    float user;
    int change, coins, decimals;

    do
    {
       printf("Enter change amount\n");
       user = get_float("");
    } while (user <= 0);

    change = user * 100;
    coins = 0; 

    while (change >= 25)
    {
        change = change - 25;
        coins++;
    }

    while (change >= 10)
    {
       change = change - 10;
       coins++;
    }

    while (change >= 5)
    {
       change = change - 5;
       coins++;
    }

    while (change >= 1)
    {
        change = change - 1;
        coins++;
    }

    printf("You have entered\f%.1f\n", user);
    sleep(1);
    printf("The least amount of coins possible\f%.2d\n", coins);
}
```

Error messages that I keep getting:
:( input of 0.01 yields output of 1
    expected "1\n", not "You have enter..." **this actually returns back 01 so not sure**
:( input of 1.6 yields output of 7
    expected "7\n", not "You have enter..."  **same thing just 07 is there a way to remove the zero?**

:( input of 4.2 yields output of 18
    expected "18\n", not "You have enter..."
    did you forget to round your input to the nearest cent?

**This one I'm not sure it yields an output of 22**

Comment: What are the contents of `<cs50.h>`?

Comment: Although, looking closer at your expected output, are you not getting the results you expect? Do you know what `'\n'` is?

Comment: I assume the checking program just want you to print a number, without that friendly text. A few other notes: You don't need to use `printf` to prompt for a float (`get_float` supports prompting for input). Calculations may be done with integer divisions and modulus, no need for loops.  If you don't want leading zeros when printing integers, then don't ask for them in your format string.

Comment: @sweenish, `cs50.h` is the header to a memory leaking input library used by the harward cs50 course. Its pros is that it teaches students not to use `scanf` for input. Major con is that it defines `typedef char * string` and its string input is written in a way that makes fixing memory leaks impossible.

Comment: @HAL9000, interesting. I was assuming that `get_float()` was coming from it; I'm having a hard time seeing why it needs to be initialized with an empty string literal. When I taught, Intro never bothered with input validation as it's too big of a rabbit hole to bother those students with. Later courses only went so far as "take it as a string and run some basic validations on it." This code looks like the C++ tag should be removed.

Comment: @sweenish <cs50.h> is a source code / library provided by Harvard for the CS 50 Course. It really just helps you understand how to code. I have provided a link as well for more information

Comment: [link] (https://cs50.readthedocs.io/library/c/) @sweenish. I am getting expected results for the test for 0.01 it yields 01 but I think it only passes the test if it yields 1, same for the 7. I am not yielding expected results for the input of 4.2 it yields 22 instead of 18.

Comment: @HAL9000 very new to coding, so please bare with me. Which one is my format string, we haven't used that term in the class. Thank you for that note, much appreciated anyway I can clean up my code is helpful. Anyways I got rid of the friendly text, and it gave me more check errors, even though the program runs fine.

Comment: @HAL9000 input of 4.2 yields output of 18
    expected "18\n", not "\x0c22\n"
    did you forget to round your input to the nearest cent, this is the error when I remove the friendly text. Thank you guys for helping btw.

Comment: @sweenish and yes I know what /n is it; it was explained that it basically gets rid of the $ in the terminal.

Comment: hey guys, again thanks, here is the exact check50 errors from their website [link] (https://submit.cs50.io/check50/d5a38509d9c3b54baed04b4ee2e5237c9a25df69

Comment: @studies That is not what `'\n'` is. Not even close. You must be using zsh, because bash won't have a $ "to get rid of".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `22` rather than `18` for the input `4.20` is because of inexactness in floating point. Floats can not represent the value `4.20` exactly, so it will store a value slightly larger, or slightly smaller than `4.20` in your variable.

In the case that a slightly smaller value is used (for instance 4.1999999 or 4.19998567), when multiplying that with 100 you get something close to 419.99999. Turning that to an `int` will truncate that to 419 and give you the result of 22 coins.

The solution is to round to nearest integer, rather than truncating, when turning floats to integers. A common trick which works for small floats, is to add 0.5 before truncating:

```
 change = user * 100 + 0.5;
```

Values in the range 419.5000 to 420.4999 will be turned into values in the range 420.0000 to 420.99999. And truncating will then produce 420.

You could naturally also use the builtin rounding functions that comes with `c`.

You should also consider using `double` rather than `float`. The space saved by using `float` is typically not worth it on modern desktop systems.

Comment: Thank you that worked much appreciate and thanks for the tip. Do you know why I still receive these errors even though its correct just with a zero infront.

Comment: :( input of 1.6 yields output of 7
    expected "7\n", not "You have enter...

Comment: :( input of 0.01 yields output of 1
    expected "1\n", not "You have enter..."

Answer (score 0):

The problem set is very clear about what kind of output the program should deliver. You are not matching that. Read again.

And don't forget to round your input, as per problem set.